# Azure DevOps archive only selected files from build drop?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to archive after build tasks only selected files?
I found only "archive files" task, but it archive whole folder completely.

Comment: Have you tried the Copy Files task to copy into a side directory?  Copy Files has a filter and then you could archive that entire folder.

Comment: I know about this. I thought, there are some 3-party pack tasks, that can archive files and folders by mask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Azure DevOps archive only selected files from build drop?

I am afraid there is no such out of box task to archive **only selected** files instead of folder.

Most of the existing tasks, like `Archive files`, `Zip and unzip directory build task`, `Zip And Upload` are serving folders instead of multiple files.

Just like Josh commented, the most straightforward way is to copy multiple files into the directory and compress them together to avoid over-complicating the problem.

**But** if this question is important to you, you can try to solve this problem using a Powershell task:

```
Write-Output 'Archive selected files And folders'

$compress = @{
Path= "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\dist\test.txt", "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test2.txt"
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\Draft.Zip"
}
Compress-Archive @compress
```

[image]

Then I could archive multiple files.

If you want to multiple folder, you could use the command like:

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Reference -DestinationPath C:\Archives\Draft.zip
```

Check the document [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6) for some more details.

Hope this helps.